# actionBar.addTab throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have a method in my MainActivity Class that I access from different activity classes to instantiate Tabs in the application bar for all other activities.

However when I am making a call from a class to this function in the MainActivity class its thwroing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

My Function in `MainActivity.Java`

```
public void initiateMenuTabs(ActionBar actionBar) {

    try {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
                switch (tabPosition) {
                case 0:
                    setContentView(R.layout.event_feed);
                    break;
                case 1: {
                    Intent startClassActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            ClassWide.class);
                    startActivity(startClassActivity);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                    setContentView(R.layout.event_feed);
                    break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Event Feed")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_alarms)
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Wide")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_Wide)
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Report")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location_found)
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause().getCause());

    }

}
```

Function Calling from `ClassWide.Java`

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wide_view);
    MainActivity cObj = new MainActivity();
    cObj.initiateMenuTabs(getActionBar());
            .... ....
```

`LogCat` window shows this:

```
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.helloworld.projectone/com.helloworld.projectone.ClassWide}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at com.helloworld.projectone.MainActivity.initiateMenuTabs(MainActivity.java:79)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at com.helloworld.projectone.ClassWide.onCreate(ClassWide.java:21)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-29 15:21:09.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What's the exception report? Edit that into your question.

Comment: how can i get exception report? do you mean logCat output?

Comment: added, check now plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating an Android Activity within another Activity. An Activity is more than a simple class  in android, 
What you should do to call your method from any Activity you want is to define your BaseActivity that contains the methods that are common to all the activites and extend it instead of extending the general Activity class :

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public void initiateMenuTabs(ActionBar actionBar) {
         ....//your code
    }
}
```

then extend your BaseActivity in any other Activity that needs to call the initiateMenuTabs method

```
public ClassWide extends BaseActivity{

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wide_view);

        initiateMenuTabs(getActionBar());// here it will call the method from the parent (BaseActivity)
            .... ....
```

Comment: But not every class using this function are `Activity` driven some are also `FragmentActivity` than would i instantiate those?

Comment: FragmentActivity inherits from Activity, so no you shouldn't instantiate it like a normal class using 'new FragmentActivity' , if you want to launch an Activity you should do it via intents, and if you want to share the same method across all your activities/fragmentactivities  then you should make your method static and pass a Context as a parameter, and use the context inside the method

Comment: Or write a BaseFragmentActivity that all your fragmentActivities will extend